# Unable to connect to Abyss web server by IP

Tags: website, webserver

I installed Abyss Web Server. I'm running Windows XP Home Edition and I have Wireless Mobile Broadband internet.

I used to be able to access (and other people on other networks) my site by entering my IP address in the browser, but after I formatted, and installed Abyss web server again, this does not work anymore.

There are no errors. I CAN visit my own site by entering my IP address, BUT anybody else can't do the same - it just says "connecting" in the browser's status bar and it never changes.

I have consulted the docs and have found no help. Google hasn't helped with this problem either.

Comment: I'm not sure what other details you may need. So please do ask if you need more information from me.

Comment: Here's a title suggestion: "Can only connect to webserver from local machine"

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get other people to access your Abyss Web Server via a mobile broadband connection - it is very likely that your connection is running behind a cached proxy service provided by your ISP[1].

Alternatively, You may want to engage in a web-hosting service provider to allow you to publish your website/service.

1. Are your friends able to ping your public IP address assigned by your ISP?
2. Execute Start button -> Run -> 'cmd' -> 'ipconfig' /all (and show the first two octets only.)
3. Does the IP address stated on the returned result look similar to 192.168.x; 10.x; 172.16.x ?

*Footnote: [1] My basis for this reasoning is that ISPs would like to reduce the amount of bandwidth required to process content requests from users of mobile broadband services, thus allowing them to achieve the desired QoS as advertised to the subscriber. While this option may vary from ISPs around the world, as far as I am aware of is that most of them engage in a similar concept of proxy all mobile connections where possible.*

Comment: thank you for your answer, i think what you're saying could quite possible be whats going on here. my other users aren't all on wireless broadband but alot of them are. so am i. others have cable or dialup still... When I do the ipconfig, my ip address is: 10.228.183.51

Comment: I am asking my friends now to see if they can ping me :)

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it sounds like you have a private IP address, which means you are probably behind a NAT firewall. This is what allows many computers to connect to the internet using a single IP address, for example on a home network.

You will need to find out what your public IP is. There are a variety of web sites that will tell you, one of the simplest being http://www.whatismyip.org/. This is the address that you need to be giving out.

Get your friends to ping that address. If it works, then get them to try connecting to the same address using a browser. If that doesn't work, it's almost surely a NAT issue; you will need to configure port forwarding on whatever device (router, firewall) is stopping the traffic.